# How to be up to date with the LAMP platform?

Tags: php, lamp

Most of times I get to know about the new features too late. It is okay at least I know about them does not matter from where I know But I feel it is too late to know about those features.

I am working on LAMP platform and I want to keep myself up to date with the new things, anything happening new with LAMP.

Can you please let me know what resources should I use? What groups should I follow?
From where I can get the latest updates about any activity, event and feature about LAMP?

Comment: Subscribe to [PHP Architect](http://www.phparch.com/).

Comment: btw. LAMP itself isn't very up to date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a single authoritative source for LAMP.  A good place to start is subscribing to the news on the front pages of each of the components:  your favorite Linux distro, apache, mysql, and php.  They should all have rss feeds.  Mysql even has a facebook page.  Likewise for related technologies you may be using, such as jQuery or a CMS.

There are sites that specialize in tech news, such as [slashdot](http://slashdot.org) or [reddit](http://reddit.com).  Google news also lets you subscribe to news based on search terms, from which you will find other sources you like.

If you read questions on StackOverflow, even if you don't know enough to answer them, you will find out about the newer technologies.

Comment: [Dr. Dobb's Journal Web Dev Channel](http://drdobbs.com/web-development?itc=ddj-channel-leftnav-web-development) is a useful resource that reports on a lot of exciting developments in web development. All the material isn't LAMP specific, but it is sometimes.